# How to compile REDIS 5.0.5 on Windows-10, error in make

Tags: makefile, redis, compilation, windows-10, mingw-w64

Downloaded 5.0.5 from [Redis](https://redis.io/download)
cd to src directory
make

Surely this must work for someone else out there. Any idea/ hintg about how to fix this?

*Short version:*

In **net.c** ...

```
make[3]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/pmoran/Downloads/redis-5.0.5/deps/hiredis'
cc -std=c99 -pedantic -c -O3 -fPIC  -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -g -ggdb  net.c

net.c:270:21: error: storage size of ‘hints’ isn’t known
 struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *bservinfo, *p, *b;
                 ^~~~~
```

and later

```
net.c:337:40: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct addrinfo’
 for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
                                    ^~
```

then

```
make[3]: *** [Makefile:156: net.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/pmoran/Downloads/redis-5.0.5/deps/hiredis'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:46: hiredis] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/pmoran/Downloads/redis-5.0.5/deps'
```

and finally

```
cc: error: ../deps/hiredis/libhiredis.a: No such file or directory
cc: error: ../deps/lua/src/liblua.a: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:219: redis-server] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/pmoran/Downloads/redis-5.0.5/src'
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same exact problem and I found the best solution was to use an older version of redis. Redis 3.2.13 was updated recently (March 2019) so it has all the functionality I need. If you use it, you do have to add the following to redis-3.2.13/deps/hiredis/net.c after the 'include' statements:

```
    #ifdef __CYGWIN__
    #define TCP_KEEPCNT 8
    #define TCP_KEEPINTVL 150
    #define TCP_KEEPIDLE 14400
    #endif
```

After that I was able to run make from the root directory:

```
make distclean
make
```

This is based on [this](https://gist.github.com/pcan/44cb2177647f029d457facb31da0883f) github conversation.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try.

Step 1:
Remove segment '-std=c99' from  line 
$(CC) -std=c99 -pedantic -c $(REAL_CFLAGS) $<
in file Makefile under .\redis-5.0.5\deps\hiredis

Ste 2:
Add the following segment after includes deps/hiredis/net.c after the 'include' statements:

```
#ifndef TCP_KEEPCNT
    #define TCP_KEEPCNT 8    
#endif

#ifndef TCP_KEEPINTVL
    #define TCP_KEEPINTVL 150   
#endif

#ifndef TCP_KEEPIDLE
    #define TCP_KEEPIDLE 14400   
#endif
```